# turn my for loop into a function in python

Tags: python

I would like to know how can I turn my `for` loop into a function.

I wrote a code which asks the user to input an address, then the code iterate through preset addresses and return me the closest address to the input one.

I would like to make it a function so I can call it in my GUI.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import json

# Google Maps directions API endpoint
endpoint = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?'
api_key = 'MY API KEY'

# donner l'adresse en code postal
origin = input("Inserer l'adresse du fabricant : ").replace(' ', '+')
destinations = ['H7N 5H9', 'H4N 1P9', 'K4A 0G2']
distances = []

# Parcourt la liste des adresses et calcule chacune de leurs distances
def proximity():
    for i in range(len(destinations)):
        currentDestination = destinations[i].replace(' ', '+')
        nav_request = 'origin={}&destination={}&key={}'.format(origin, currentDestination, api_key)
        request = endpoint + nav_request
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
        directions = json.loads(response)
        distance = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"]
        distances.append(distance)
        closestDistance = min(distances)
        return closestDistance

print("the distance is: " + proximity())
print("closest address is : " + destinations[distances.index(proximity())])
```

EDIT :

i'm not getting the error below anymore though

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cn/PycharmProjects/Calendrier/venv/proximity.py", line 25, in <module>
    print("the distance is: " + closestDistance)
NameError: name 'closestDistance' is not defined
```

What I want, is to be able to call this function in my other module. 
The code works perfectly with the for loop, I just want to be able to transform it into a function.

Comment: Do you know how to write functions in general?

Comment: You write a function that does the same thing. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't know how, I tried to add `def proximity():` on top of my for loop, but something is missing. Sorry if it's too obvious.

Comment: It's OK to be obvious, it's just that in order to help you we need information. If you say you tried something - show us! And also explain exactly what went wrong - *but something is missing* is not a good problem statement that we can help you with. You can [edit] your question to be more detailed, with the help of [ask] and [mre]. Once you do I will vote to open back the question

Comment: @Tomerikoo You're right and i'm sorry, I thought It was enough information ! I edited my code... thank you for giving me a second chance!

Comment: No problem man! But again, you forgot to state what exactly is wrong. Your question is missing the actual question :) If you get an error - post it. If you get a wrong output - post it and your expected one. Right now, I just see a function that is never called so I assume you get a NameError on `closestDistance` never being defined

Comment: To post an error copy-paste everything starting with `Traceback (most recent call last)` until the end. I find it hard to believe you get that error on that line

Comment: @Tomerikoo Done ! Thank you for you patience...  hope I did it well.

Comment: Yes, I will vote to open it. For the meantime, if you use a function you need to actually call it. The `def` statement - as its name - just defines the function. But also your function doesn't `return` anything. So, try adding to the last line of the function `return closestDistance` and then doing `print("the distance is: " + proximity())`. Lastly, you shouldn't rely on global variables in your functions, so try changing to `def proximity(origin, destinations, distances):`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I did what you said, it worked, but now it doesnt give me the closest address possible. Seems like it's completely off after this little tweek.. I updated my code in op

Comment: @Tomerikoo it seems like it doesnt loop anymore and only stops at the first address on the list (H7N 5H9)

Comment: You need to unindent the `return` statement to be outside the for loop... Right now it is just returning after the first iteration. And also it would be better to do before the prints `dist = proximity()` and then use that `print("the distance is: " + dist)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you so much. i'm so thankful for your help and patience. I will take a vow to never post incomplete questions on this site ever again. Thanks again kind sir.

Comment: I am really happy to help and hope your problem is solved. The key points to take from this to avoid your questions getting closed in the future, is to try and read your own question in subjective eyes. Try to judge if for someone from outside that is not aware to your problem or knowledge it is clear. You can always use the [help] and [ask] to help you write better questions. Wish you good luck and happy coding!